# Прикладная задача на java 8 stream API

Tags: java, java-stream, java-8

Есть три класса: `A`, `B` и `C`. Класс `C` содержит поле `List<B>`, класс `B` содержит поле `List<A>`. Класс `A` никакой информации о `B` и `C` не имеет. Дан список объектов типа `C`. Необходимо с помощию `stream API` по этому списку получить карту, где каждому объекту типа `A` соответствует список тех объектов типа `B`, которые его содержат. Например, при такой конфигурации :

```
C c1 = {b1,b2};
C c2 = {b2};
B b1 = {a1,a2};
B b2 = {a3, a2};
A a1, a2, a3;
```

получить что-то вроде:

```
a1 - b1
a2 - b1, b2, b2 // повторяется 2 раза, т.к. b2 встречается и в c1, и в c2
a3 - b2, b2 // аналогично
```

Всё это должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
List<C> c_s = Arrays.asList(c1,c2);
Map<...,...> map = c_s.stream()
.map(...)
//...
.collect(...);
```

Дополнительную информацию в `A`,`B` и `C` вводить нельзя, возможно, стоит добавить какие-то дополнительные классы.

Comment: обязательно map и  collect ?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor думаю, это для примера только написано. Лично я на ночь глядя так и не осилил решить эту задачу (которая запросто решается тройным циклом) в функциональном стиле. Что делать после получения общего `bList` из `cList` (он же `c_s`) - непонятно.

Answer (score 2):

Все довольно просто.

Во-первых, С сами по себе ни в чем не участвуют и просто являются источником В, поэтому перва операция - это явно `.flatMap()` с получением `Stream<B>`, и дальше работа производится только над B и A. Здесь появляется дополнительное условие: работа ведется над списком A, но требуется сохранить связь с B, поэтому вводится дополнительный класс, содержащий в себе обоих, и операции производятся уже над ним

```
public class Alpha {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a1 = new A(1);
        A a2 = new A(2);
        A a3 = new A(3);

        B b1 = new B(1).add(a1).add(a2);
        B b2 = new B(2).add(a3).add(a2);

        C c1 = new C(1).add(b1).add(b2);
        C c2 = new C(2).add(b2);

        List<C> composition = Arrays.asList(c1, c2);
        System.out.println("Initial composition: " + composition);
        Map<A, List<B>> result = composition.stream()
                .flatMap(item -> item.getChildren().stream())
                .flatMap(item -> item.getChildren().stream().map(child -> new Pair<>(item, child)))
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(
                                Pair::getY,
                                pair -> Collections.singletonList(pair.getX()),
                                (left, right) -> Stream.concat(left.stream(), right.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())
                        )
                );
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    }

    private static class A {
        private final int value;

        public A(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "A" + value;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Integer.hashCode(value);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (o == this) {
                return true;
            }
            if (!(o instanceof A)) {
                return false;
            }
            return value == ((A) o).value;
        }
    }

    private static class B {

        private final List<A> children = new ArrayList<>();
        private final int value;

        public B(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public B add(A a) {
            children.add(a);
            return this;
        }

        public List<A> getChildren() {
            return new ArrayList<>(children);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "B" + value + " " + children;
        }
    }

    private static class C {

        private final List<B> children = new ArrayList<>();
        private final int value;

        public C(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public C add(B b) {
            children.add(b);
            return this;
        }

        public List<B> getChildren() {
            return new ArrayList<>(children);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "C" + value + " " + children;
        }
    }

    public static class Pair<X, Y> {
        private final X x;
        private final Y y;

        public Pair(X x, Y y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public X getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public Y getY() {
            return y;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
Initial composition: [C1 [B1 [A1, A2], B2 [A3, A2]], C2 [B2 [A3, A2]]]
Result: {A1=[B1 [A1, A2]], A2=[B1 [A1, A2], B2 [A3, A2], B2 [A3, A2]], A3=[B2 [A3, A2], B2 [A3, A2]]}
```

Сюда очень хорошо зашел бы `Collectors.groupingBy()`, но из-за условий задачи его нельзя применить.

Comment: Насчет "всё довольно просто" вы таки загнули) Лично я тогда с добрый час пытался решить эту задачу, и так и не осилил в функциональном стиле. Первый `flatMap` - это понятно, а вот сохранить связь между `A` и `B`  с помощью скрещивания `flatMap` с `map` я не догадался. `toMap`, кстати, тоже вышел не из простых. Насчет `groupingBy` -  в самом вопросе ведь ничего не говорится по поводу того, что можно использовать, а что - нет. Главное - функциональное решение.

Comment: @Regent размер кода != сложность

Comment: Однако до этого решения дойти не так и просто. Ну или я просто слишком мало работал со Stream-ами.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class A {

    String name;
}

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class B {

    private String name;
    private List<A> aList;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
public class C {

    List<B> bList;
}

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Current {

    private A key;
    private B value;
}

public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A a1 = new A("A1");
        A a2 = new A("A2");
        A a3 = new A("A3");

        B b1 = new B("B1", Arrays.asList(a1, a2));
        B b2 = new B("B2", Arrays.asList(a3, a2));

        C c1 = new C(Arrays.asList(b1, b2));
        C c2 = new C(List.of(b2));

        List<C> composition = Arrays.asList(c1, c2);
        Map<String, String> result = composition.stream()
                .flatMap(c -> c.bList.stream())
                .flatMap(b -> b.getAList().stream()
                        .map(a -> new Current(a, b)))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        current -> current.getKey().getName(),
                        current -> current.getValue().getName(),
                        (o, o2) -> String.join(", ", o, o2)));
        System.out.println("result = " + result);
    }
}

result = {A1=B1, A2=B1, B2, B2, A3=B2, B2}
```

Comment: Очень похоже на ответ `etki`, также не уверен, что в качестве значения требовалось получить именно строку, а не список

Answer (score -1):

пропущу описание классов A, B, C

```
    A a1 = new A();
    A a2 = new A();
    A a3 = new A();

    B b1 = new B();
    b1.aList.add(a1);
    b1.aList.add(a2);

    B b2 = new B();
    b2.aList.add(a3);
    b2.aList.add(a2);

    C c1 = new C();
    c1.bList.add(b1);
    c1.bList.add(b2);


    C c2 = new C();
    c2.bList.add(b2);

    Map<A, List<Object>>res = new HashMap<>();
    Arrays.asList(c1, c2).stream()
        .forEach(cElems -> // проходимся по элементам c1 и c2
                     cElems.bList.forEach(bElems -> // элементы класса В
                                  bElems.aList.forEach(
                                  aElems -> { // элементы класса А
                                      if(res.containsKey(aElems)) // если уже есть объект A
                                      {
                                          res.get(aElems).add(bElems); // то добавляем к существующему
                                      }else { // иначе новый создаем
                                          List<Object> bs = new ArrayList<>();
                                          bs.add(bElems);
                                          res.put(aElems, bs);
                                      }
                                  }))
        );

    System.out.println(res.size());

}
```

Comment: Ну не, так не интересно. Хочется действительно функциональное решение, а не запись тройного цикла с помощью `forEach`.

Comment: согласен. как раз жду такого решения, мне тоже очень интересно. проблемы возникают, когда тебе нужно сохранять bElems.